# Python - OpenCV: calibrateCamera returning camera matrix, but it is nonsensical

Tags: python, image, opencv, distortion

I am trying to get rid of barrel and other distortive effects in images to apply specifically to coordinates. I am using openCV with the chessboard, I have managed to get accurate corners - however, when I apply these corners I find that they do not return what I expect.

image: [the orginal image: calibrationImage.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyi5X.png)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('calibrationImage.bmp')
corners = array([[[136.58304, 412.18762]],

       [[200.73372, 424.21613]],

       [[263.41006, 431.9114 ]],

       [[334.     , 437.     ]],

       [[405.     , 436.     ]],

       [[470.78467, 428.75998]],

       [[530.23724, 420.48328]],

       [[152.61916, 358.20523]],

       [[210.78505, 368.59222]],

       [[270.52335, 371.8065 ]],

       [[335.67096, 373.8901 ]],

       [[400.88788, 373.57782]],

       [[462.57724, 371.10867]],

       [[517.49524, 366.26855]],

       [[168.55394, 310.78973]],

       [[228.     , 321.     ]],

       [[277.43225, 319.48358]],

       [[336.7225 , 320.90256]],

       [[396.0194 , 321.13016]],

       [[452.47888, 320.15744]],

       [[503.7933 , 318.09518]],

       [[183.49014, 270.53726]],

       [[231.8806 , 273.96835]],

       [[283.5549 , 275.63623]],

       [[337.41528, 276.47876]],

       [[391.28375, 276.99832]],

       [[442.8828 , 277.16376]],

       [[490.67108, 276.5398 ]],

       [[196.86388, 236.63716]],

       [[241.56177, 238.3809 ]],

       [[288.93515, 239.1635 ]],

       [[337.9244 , 239.63228]],

       [[386.90695, 240.31389]],

       [[434.21832, 241.17548]],

       [[478.62744, 241.05113]],

       [[208.81688, 208.1463 ]],

       [[250.11485, 208.97067]],

       [[293.5653 , 208.92986]],

       [[338.2928 , 209.22559]],

       [[382.94626, 209.92468]],

       [[426.362  , 211.03403]],

       [[467.76523, 210.82764]],

       [[219.20187, 184.123  ]],

       [[257.52582, 184.09167]],

       [[297.4925 , 183.80571]],

       [[338.5172 , 183.91574]],

       [[379.46725, 184.64926]],

       [[419.45697, 185.74242]],

       [[457.93872, 185.08537]],

       [[228.31578, 163.70671]],

       [[263.87802, 163.11162]],

       [[300.8062 , 162.71281]],

       [[338.686  , 162.79945]],

       [[376.43716, 163.36848]],

       [[413.39032, 164.23444]],

       [[449.21677, 163.16547]]], dtype=float32)

w, h = 7, 8
objp = np.zeros((h*w, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:w, 0:h].T.reshape(-1, 2)
img_points = []
obj_points = []
img_points.append(corners)
obj_points.append(objp)
image_size = (img.shape[1], img.shape[0])

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = (obj_points, img_points, image_size, None, None)

updatedCorners = cv2.undistortPoints(corners, mtx, dist, P=mtx)
updatedCorners = updatedCorners.reshape([56,2])

ret = True
checkers = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7, 8), corners, ret)

fig, (img_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12,12))
img_ax.imshow(checkers)
img_ax.scatter(updatedCorners.T[0], updatedCorners.T[1], c='orange')
```

I was trying see how good the calibration was by plotting corners run through the undistort function. however, when I plot them they are all over the place

[image: strange undistorted points in orange]

Does anyone know what has gone wrong?

Comment: I don't think you should specify 'P' in undistortPoints.

Comment: how many pictures do you use for calibration

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I used just the one picture - The camera does not change its perspective.

Comment: Can you please edit your post so that you provide the actual source in text form instead of an image?  Snapshots of source code is frowned upon here and people will be less inclined to help you.  Also, it's highly recommended you have more than one image with different perspectives to calibrate your camera.  You have also omitted the code that finds the actual corners (the `corners` variable).  Using just one image generally does not provide good results under extreme distortion.

Comment: Please edit your code as a __text__ [mre] into your question instead of a useless (in terms of running your code to see the same problem) picture.

Comment: a single picture is not enough for calibration. it *will* give you bad results.

Comment: @rayryeng apologies - I've updated my post to show code. The corners were pre-calculated by someone elses MatLab code - not using cv2. I just found the corners in a large matlab file. initially I tried using the findChessCorners method but it would not return enough corners. I do not have access to any more calibration pictures and its important that I get these images to work.

Comment: Your code doesn’t include imports, and where is corners defined, is there anything else missing? Please make your code a [mre] - anyone should be able to paste your code and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same results as you. Try it yourself: paste the code in your question and run it, does it work - if you want people to help your code should be a [mre]. Please read [ask]

Comment: Only one perspective is not enough to properly obtain the right camera parameters.  At this point you're trying to squeeze water out of a stone and I can't help you any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.undistortPoints` expects the camera matrix and distortion coefficients retrieved from calibration.  You are supplying the wrong information to it.  You currently have the camera matrix and distortion coefficients set to the object points and image size.  You can also remove `P`.  You would only specify this if you intend to map the undistorted points to another coordinate system.  Since you are double checking what the undistorted points look like, specifying `P` as the same camera matrix you found earlier would simply map it back to where you originally found the points which is not what you're after.

Here is a minimal working example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

camera_matrix = np.array([[1300., 0., 600], [0., 1300., 480.], [0., 0., 1.]], dtype=np.float32)

dist_coeffs = np.array([-2.4, 0.95, -0.0004, 0.00089, 0.], dtype=np.float32)

test = np.zeros((10, 1, 2), dtype=np.float32)
xy_undistorted = cv2.undistortPoints(test, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)

print(xy_undistorted)
```

The camera matrix is a 3 x 3 matrix retrieved from calibration, followed by the distortion coefficients being a 1D NumPy array.  `test` is a 3D NumPy array with a singleton second dimension.  Ensure that every variable is of type `np.float32`, then run the function.

However I am skeptical that you will obtain decent results with just one perspective.  You usually need more if you are calibrating a camera subject to large distortion.  Nevertheless, the above is what you need to get the method working.

Comment: Okay you are correct about me not having enough images. However, is there an alternative function to calibrateCamera and undistort where you can use the points of a single image checkerboard - even if the results are not as impressive? It important to note I do not need dimensions - only x and y. so If the image can be stretched in a way to allow the checkerboard to be square that would suit me